# Google Charts error with Chrome: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-visualization

As the title says, I am getting this error when trying to load a simple Column Chart: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined"

This only happens in Google Chrome, while Firefox displays it without problems.
I tried to find a solution, but I can't figure out the problem. `google.load` is there by the way, this is the full jQuery script:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                current = 0;

                var jsondata1 =$.ajax({url: "index.php?action=stats&data=post",dataType:"json",async: false}).responseText;
                var jsondata2 =$.ajax({url: "index.php?action=stats&data=comm",dataType:"json",async: false}).responseText;
                var jsondata3 =$.ajax({url: "index.php?action=stats&data=like",dataType:"json",async: false}).responseText;
                var jsondata4 =$.ajax({url: "index.php?action=stats&data=disl",dataType:"json",async: false}).responseText;

                var data = [];
                data[0] = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata1);
                data[1] = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata2);
                data[2] = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata3);
                data[3] = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata4);
                var title = ["post","comments","likes","dislikes"];

                var options = {
                    width:600,
                    height:500,
                    vAxis: {title: "Number"},
                    hAxis: {title: "Users"},
                    legend: {position: 'none'},
                    animation:{
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'out',
                    },
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('graphimg'));

                function drawChart() {
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',function() {});
                    options['title'] = 'Max number of '+title[current];
                    chart.draw(data[current], options);
                }

                function next(){
                    current++;
                    if(current === 4)
                        current = 0;
                    drawChart();
                }

                function prev(){
                    current--;
                    if(current < 0)
                        current = 3;
                    drawChart();
                }
```

The data is obtained from the ajax calls, the requests are handled by similar php functions, here is one (don't mind the deprecated MySQL calls):

```
function getMaxLikes(){
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $sql = "SELECT username, count( user ) AS numlikes
            FROM users, likes
            WHERE user = username and value=1
            GROUP BY username
            ORDER BY numlikes DESC
            LIMIT 5";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error:".mysql_error());

    $json = array();
    $json['cols'] = array(
            array('label' => 'User', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'Likes', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'style')
    );

    $rows = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['username']);

        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['numlikes']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $this->color[$i]);
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        $i++;
    }

    $json['rows'] = $rows;
    return json_encode($json);
}
```

The json format seems right to me, but I could be mistaken.
What could cause the problem? Thanks in advance!